# Does class object on Heap also store its method details?

Tags: java, c#, memory-management, compilation

I am reading about memory management of OOP. i understand call stacks and how object instantiation on heap. How OS POP and Push call stack  data to register. How unrefrenced garbage is collected from heap by GC thread. 
I also understand how function pointer (delegate) which created on virtual space work to point to ther function.

My QUESTION is when object get instantiated does it also store method details of its type(class) on HEAP OR just it internally used by compiler just like identifer name ?  just like int is 4 byte on heap, i wan to know  how in just 4 bytes, method varible also get stored ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every object stored on the heap consist of **(i)** a header block, and **(ii)** data, in your case an `int`.

The header block tells .NET the type of the object and the valid operations for the type, which are part of the compiled code in program memory.

For a deep dive into this, see here:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/03/15/virtual-method-dispatch-and-object-layout-changes-in-clr-40/

Comment: thank you, please comment back if i am right.   > all big the method we create is just above the compiler , below the compiler ,compiler parsing it down to push and pop ISA intruction , object data (like properties) store in heap , refrence is stored in stack. after computation it get garbage collected from heap .